# Unable to require('child_process').spawn, console says spawn is not a function, Python-Shell node package

Tags: node.js, child-process, spawn

I am attempting to use an external package:

```
npm install [python-shell][1]
```

Right now, I have just the basic js file with the example the package comes with:

```
console.log('hey in main.js')
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');

PythonShell.run('./my_script.py', function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('finished running python script');
});
```

Along with `my_script.py`, etc

When I start up the server, the console.log says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: spawn is not a function
```

Within the index.js of the python-shell package, spawn is required correctly ([similar case](https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node/issues/173)):

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
```

And later, it is used in the package like so:

```
this.childProcess = spawn(pythonPath, this.command, options);
```

However, `spawn` does seem to be a function:

```
master$>node
> require('child_process')
{ ChildProcess: 
   { [Function: ChildProcess]
     super_: 
      { [Function: EventEmitter]
        EventEmitter: [Circular],
        usingDomains: true,
        defaultMaxListeners: 10,
        init: [Function],
        listenerCount: [Function] } },
  fork: [Function],
  _forkChild: [Function],
  exec: [Function],
  execFile: [Function],
  spawn: [Function],
  spawnSync: [Function: spawnSync],
  execFileSync: [Function: execFileSync],
  execSync: [Function: execSync] }
```

So I'm not sure why console says it is not a function.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this same problem trying to run code like this

```
var spawn = require('child_process')
var child = spawn('pwd')
```

would result in error

```
 TypeError: spawn is not a function
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/sailor/advancedNode/child_cluster_exec/spawn.js:5:13)
```

however, adding spawn to the require fixed it

```
 var spawn = require('child_process').spawn
 var child = spawn('pwd')
```

OR

```
      var {spawn} = require('child_process')
```

this works fine....

Comment: does not seem to work in reactjs apps: `TypeError: spawn is not a function`

Comment: having the same issue with the react app :/

Comment: spawn is a node function.  Are you trying to run this in the browser??  It will only work on your server

Answer (score 0):

Use this under Windows:

```
const cp = require('child_process');
const cmd = cp.spawn('cmd');
cmd.on('exit',(data)=>{
  console.log(data);
});
```

spawn is not a "normal" function as usual, it has no default name string like the others.